# How to rename all the files in a folder in numeric order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

The folder "Photos" has more than 800 images in it.  I want to rename all of them in numeric order, starting with 1.

All I could get is the below code.  It looks right to me but it doesn't work.  I get an error on the `rename`:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Code:

```
import os

x = 0

for i in os.listdir("E:\\Photos"): 
    if  i.endswith(".jpg"):
        os.rename(i, x)
        x+=1
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Is the script also in `E:\Photos`? I don't think `rename` looks anywhere other than the current working directory unless you specify a path explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rename` takes two strings; you gave it an integer.  Try something like this:

```
os.rename(i, str(x))
```

or even a descriptive name, of this form:

```
os.rename(i, "photo" + str(x) + ".jpg")
```

If you want three-digit numbering (i.e. "photo001.jpg" instead of "photo1.jpg"), then check out the `<string>.format` method.

Comment: Sweet !! this worked.. I converted the x into str(x).

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.  Alternately, if you feel it's too trivial, just delete the whole question.

Comment: I tried to upvote but as I'm new to Stackoverflow I do not have enough reputation to do so. But thank you, the code did work.

Comment: Glad to help.  As long as the question is properly retired, I'm fine.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, the os.rename function won't accept an integer.

I'm sure there's a more pythonic way to write this but here's an answer based solely on your code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.4
    import os

    x = 0
    photo_dir=os.path.dirname(__file__)+"\\photos\\"
    extension = ".jpg"
    for i in os.listdir(photo_dir): 
        if  i.endswith(extension):
            os.rename(photo_dir+i, photo_dir+str(x)+extension)
            x+=1
```

Comment: Thanks!!  Yes I converted the integer into string and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in PowerShell that has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62672805/4044579):

As a quick note:

```
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path '.' -File | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:D4}.png' -f $script:count++ }
```

Comment: You need to be sure the author wants to achieve the same thing in the post you shared

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
folderPath = r'E:\Photos'
fileSequence = 1

for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    os.rename(filename, 'image_' + str(fileSequence)+".JPG")
    fileSequence +=1
```

If you want to name it like `image_1` , `image_2`  etc.. then you can use the above portion otherwise remove `image_` from the above code. The rest will work perfectly fine.