# Powershell: How to batch rename files in chronological order and sorted by Date

Tags: powershell

I have more than 1000 photos that I want to rename into "ngimg-" therefore should yield "ngimg-1 , ngimg-2, ngimg-3..." and on and on until the last photo.

I would like to use PowerShell for this task instead of installing third party applications.

I've tried this code here but it's not the proper one for this task

```
Dir *.jpg | sort Date | ForEach-Object -begin { $count=1 }  -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "image$count.jpg"; $count++ }
```

I'm not sure if that code above is right. I just made it up from this:

```
Dir *.jpg | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count=1 }  -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "image$count.jpg"; $count++ }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Update: To add to my question, I want to have the files sorted by date first and then be renamed, therefore, it should be like this:

```
01/01/2020 = ngimg-1
01/02/2020 = ngimg-2
01/03/2020 = ngimg-3
...and so on
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would format the count number with 4 digits, since you have (more than) 1000 images, so they will sort correctly after renaming them.

Something like this:

```
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.jpg' -File |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
Rename-Item -NewName { 'ngimg-{0:D4}{1}' -f $script:count++, $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Take off the `-WhatIf` safety switch if you have seen the code would have renamed all files as you like. With tha switch on, no file is actually renamed.

The `$script:count++` is needed here because otherwise, the scriptblock for `Rename-Item` does not know the `$count` variable and then the index number will not be incremented on each file.

<sup>Of course, change the path `'D:\Test'` into the folder path where your image files are..</sup>

---

To demonstrate here two screenshots.

**Before:**

[image]

As you can see in the second column (Date) the files are now shown sorted by Name, so the file dates are not in chronoligical order.

**After:**

[image]

After renaming, the dates ARE in chronological order while still we show the list sorted by Name.

Comment: Hi @Theo thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out. The code you shared is perfect! However, i did forgot to mention in my question that what's truly important for me is that the files are renamed after being sorted by creation time.

For example, 

ngimg-1 = 01/01/2020
ngimg-2 = 01/02/2020
ngimg-3 = 01/03/2020

If you more spare time, I'd appreciate if you can update the code you shared above :)

Comment: @TheAuthor In that case, use the `CreationTime` instead of `LastWriteTime`

Comment: I copied the code above and updated it with CreationTime, but it's still renaming the files randomly (not by ascending order, date mm/dd/yyyy). :(

Comment: I'm really hoping to rename the files in ascending order by date, so that the oldest file will be #1 and the latest will be the last, and everything else in between the two. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @TheAuthor Well, my code sorts the files by their `LastWriteTime` property so that the oldest file is on top. If you want that reversed, simply add the `-Descending` switch there. The LastWriteTime property is the Modified date  you see in explorer. The `MM/dd/yyyy` date format you mention is **NOT** a sortable format. For that you want `yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: @TheAuthor I have added images to show what happens and why the code does what you ask (rename oldest file as #1, followed by the second-to-oldest as #2 etc). P.S. My pc is Dutch, so the date format you see in the images is `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: genius man, worked just fantastic for me, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @js2010 I think you need to make sure your `Sort` operation finishes before pipelining it to the rename. This is easily done with parenthesis like below.

```
$count = 1
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.jpg' -File | Sort CreationTime) | Rename-Item -NewName { 'ngimg-{0:D4}{1}' -f $script:count++, $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

With so many pictures it might be trying to batch the execution. The parenthesis makes sure it finishes sorting before it starts renaming.

Answer (score 1):

That should work, more or less.  I would put parentheses around the first part so it finishes first (the sorting probably does the same thing).  I assume you want to sort by lastwritetime, since you don't state it in the question.

```
dir | select name,LastWriteTime

Name      LastWriteTime
----      -------------
file1.jpg 7/1/2020 10:19:26 AM
file2.jpg 7/1/2020 10:19:30 AM
file3.jpg 7/1/2020 10:19:33 AM


(Dir *.jpg) | sort LastWriteTime | ForEach { $count=1 } { rename-item $_ -NewName ngimg-$count.jpg -whatif; $count++ }

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\js\foo\file1.jpg Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\ngimg-1.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\js\foo\file2.jpg Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\ngimg-2.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\js\foo\file3.jpg Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\ngimg-3.jpg".
```

Answer (score 0):

For those, who want to sort the files by EXIF "Date taken" instead of LastWriteTime:

```
function Get-ExifDateTaken($filePath) {
    $image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $filePath
    $propertyItem = $image.GetPropertyItem(36867)  # PropertyId for Date Taken
    $dateTaken = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($propertyItem.Value)
    return $dateTaken
}
$count = 1
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.jpg' -File | Sort-Object { Get-ExifDateTaken $_.FullName }) |
Rename-Item -NewName { 'ngimg-{0:D4}{1}' -f $script:count++, $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```